# How to make overlay plots of a variable, but every plot than i want to make has a different length of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, overlay

I want to overlay 30 plots, each of those is the Temperature of one day, to make at the end a comparison of the develop of the Temperature and how much differ from one day to another , the problem is that when i separate the data(separate the 30 days) in pandas, every day data set has different length,for example the first day has 54977 Temperature data , and the second day has 54988 ant the third also differ so the thing I want in resume is: overlay 30 plots and in the resultant graphic the x axis use the time ticks of the first day, and the other 29 plots just match to those ticks and reduce the data to a limit in the plot to make them all start from a point a finish in other it doesnt matter if some hours or data get lost, i just want to make something like this(see last image).

The code so far is this, im not very good in python so dont judge my long code

```
`
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import datetime as dt
import calendar
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt 
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import seaborn as sns
>
datos = pd.read_csv("Jun2018T.txt", sep = ',', names=('Fecha', 'Hora', 'RADNETA', 'RADCORENT', 'RADCORSAL', 'RADINFENT', 'RADINFSAL', 'TEMP'))
>
datos['Hora'] = datos['Hora'].str[:9]
datos['Hora']
>
Dia01Jun2018 = datos[datos['Fecha'] == "2018-06-01"]
>
tiempo01=Dia01Jun2018['Hora']
temp01=Dia01Jun2018['TEMP']
>
imagen = plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
plt.plot(tiempo01,temp01)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 54977, 7000)) #the number 54977 is the last data that the first day has, the second day has a different length an so on with the rest of the days
plt.xlabel("Tiempo (H:M:S)(Formato 24 Horas)")
plt.ylabel("Temperatura (K)")
plt.title("Día 01 Jun 2018")
plt.show()
imagen.savefig('D1JUN2018')
`
```

The code above repeats for every day, maybe with a cycle is more quickly but i don handle python very good.

And the result of this is this graph is the next one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuI5F.png)

The graph that i want is  this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02DK7.png)

Mi data is represented in this form

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbs6R.png)

and this are the formats

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WO4M.png)

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: I already edit the post, you can check it. Every help is welcome thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood your question right, that you want to plot all days in a single plot, you have togenerate one figure, plt.plot() all days before you finally plt.show() the image including all plots made before. Try something like shown below:

(as I don't know your data, I don't know if this code would work. the concept should be clear at least.)

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import datetime as dt
import calendar
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt 
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import seaborn as sns
>
datos = pd.read_csv("Jun2018T.txt", sep = ',', names=('Fecha', 'Hora', 'RADNETA', 'RADCORENT', 'RADCORSAL', 'RADINFENT', 'RADINFSAL', 'TEMP'))
>
datos['Hora'] = datos['Hora'].str[:9]

>

imagen = plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))

for day in range(1,31):
    dia = datos[datos['Fecha'] == "2018-06-"+(f"{day:02d}")]
    tiempo= pd.to_datetime(dia['HORA'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
    temp= dia['TEMP']
    plt.plot(tiempo, temp)

#plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 54977, 7000)) 
plt.xlabel("Tiempo (H:M:S)(Formato 24 Horas)")
plt.ylabel("Temperatura (K)")
plt.title("Jun 2018")
plt.show()
imagen.savefig('JUN2018')
```

For the second part of your question:
as your data is stored with an timestamp, you can transform it to pandas time objects. Using them for plots, the x-axis should not have an offset anymore. I've modified the `tiempo =...` assignment in the code above.

The x-tics should automatically be in time mode now.

Comment: Ok thank you, I modify the post and put screenshots of how mi data looks and the modifications that I made it so maybe will be more clearly to explain.Thank you so much. Im uploading the data in a cloud once the upload is ready i will share you the link for you can check it.

Comment: Hey Mig B thank you so much, this is the link https://mega.nz/#!cDQGCISJ!LUD9JhJIOVGyhmS8iyHQo6x9V9KWUdfR0_T882PAv0c to the text data JUN2018T if you can check it.

Comment: Hey Mig B thank you much I already have the link of the text data data https://mega.nz/#!cDQGCISJ!LUD9JhJIOVGyhmS8iyHQo6x9V9KWUdfR0_T882PAv0c if you want to check it. Thank you so much

Comment: Hey Mig B thank you i already did it and the plot works perfectly thank you so much, one question, how can i made all the plots in the same color or make a legend?

Comment: Mig B, if i want to remove some days from the plot like the day 7 16 19 and 20 what modification i have to do?. Thanks sorry for bother so much

Comment: you could write your loop as `for day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,...]:` and add your plot function like `plt.plot(tiempo, temp, color = 'red')`

Comment: Mig B thank you so much you are awesome!! This is my email danielchacon95@hotmail.com if you want to keep in touch send me and email :D

Comment: One last consult Mig B, now you know mi data set, how i can do if i want to calculate the min value, the max value, the mean and standard deviation of the Temperature for each day every 10 minutes in total get aprox 144 values for each day.Thank you for help i really apreciate it.

Comment: If someone can help me with other problem that i have here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58387195/how-i-can-calculate-the-max-min-value-the-mean-and-standard-deviation-of-a-vari